# In Parallel resonance circuit mentioned below, is current equal for Resistor and Inductor?

Tags: components, current-measurement, parallel, passive-networks, current-divider

[image: Circuit diagram]

[image: Phasor diagram]

The parallel capacitor will have current leading voltage by 90°. In the case of Resistor and Inductor (which are in series with each other but they both are parallel to capacitor). Now, the upper half of circuit(containing resistor and inductor) should have same current as per intuition(since they are in series). But if they have same current through them then, Current through resistor(ILcosθ) and current through inductor(ILsinθ) must be equal,which implies θ=45°. This concludes that whatever inductance be in the circuit, current in upper half will always lag voltage by 45°. This seems somewhat mistaken.

When I consulted to the teahcer, he said that the resistor and the inductor will have different current through them, (due to inductor behaviour against change of current). But isn't this against basic law that the components in series will have same current thorough them?

So, I wanted to be sure, what actually is happening in the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The resistor and inductor are in series, so they have the same current. Your teacher was either mistaken or misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: That means phase angle for IL(L is subscript) will be constant irrespective of the inductance used in the circuit.

Comment: It's the same current, but that alone doesn't define the phase angle. The phase angle will depend on frequency as well as the relative magnitudes of the resistance and inductance; observe how these three circuits behave in this online simulator, for example: https://tinyurl.com/y74wfk76

Comment: So, the conclusion is current will be the same. Now, usual method for calculation gives , phase difference (θ)=45°. So, could you add some mathematical approach to calculate the phase angle.

Comment: I can't, because I need to get to sleep. Someone else perhaps can.

Comment: It's okay, afterall your health is more important.